# Transforming a 8x8, 4x4 and 1x1 square into a 9x9 square

Tags: puzzle, transformation, dissection

Good day to all of you!

I have a puzzle which I just cannot solve. I attached a photo of it. The task is to transform the shape on the left into a 9x9 square (on the right) using ONLY 2 "cuts" - dividing it into 3 separate objects. Mirroring, rotating of them is allowed. You do not have to cut in a straight line, creating zig-zags, etc. is allowed. (please ignore the random functions at the bottom). Do you have any suggestions or potential solution? Thank you very much!

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: Almost got it for $2$ cuts into $4$ pieces. Are we sure this has a solution? https://i.imgur.com/eloJmXV.png

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It was given as an extra task for bonus points at my friend's university - prof claimed that there is a solution but it cost also him a fair amount of time. So I am pretty sure there is a solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining where the problem came from :) It's kind of a trivial point but the right side edge of the shape is $>9$ so one cut has to end on the right side edge.

Comment: I can come up with $2$ ways of doing it in $5$ pieces but nothing better, yet. https://imgur.com/qnI99hg https://imgur.com/cs9qUeL

Comment: Another one with $5$ pieces. https://imgur.com/k2mhAi2.

Comment: This paper https://web.cs.umass.edu/publication/docs/2011/UM-CS-2011-028.pdf gives an algorithm for computing the dissection. I think I've almost got it with $3$ pieces: https://imgur.com/thtxeSM

Comment: Are you sure the 1x1 square is not on the right side of the 4x4 square? Then it would be the famous Sam Loyd's [A Square Deal](http://www.jwstelly.org/CyclopediaOfPuzzles/PuzzlePage.php?puzzleid=Pz143.1) puzzle. However, on the left side it would cut the long thin piece into two.

Comment: I asked my friend to double-check and confirm that the drawing is correct - I let you know once I get the answer. However, the picture was taken during class - copied from the whiteboard, so I tend to be positive about its correctness. But I will make it sure. The Sam Loyd's puzzle is a brilliant input here, thank you Momo. If this turns out to be an incorrect puzzle I owe you all a beer. Or more.

Comment: Jam the one "almost good" with 3 pieces, only missing one square is impressive - but if the cutting is so complex I do not wonder I got utterly stuck with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\color{white}{Blah blah, I must write some words, I am a human.}$
[image]

Comment: Incredible! Thank you for your effort - but who knows, looking at your solution and comment it may have been no challenge for you at all. Thank you, and all of you, highly appreciated!

Comment: I saw your problem just before bedtime & scratched a failed solution. When I got up ... there it was. Thank you, what a nice puzzle. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Hope you don't mind me making your useless text go *poof\*